# Plotting 2 columns as 2 lines and 1 column as x axis on Dataframes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to pandas and all these dataframe. I am interested to know how I could transform my current codes to plt.figure instead. I would like to plot 2 columns (Tourism Receipts, Visitors) as line while putting another column as the x axis (Quarters).

It seems that this code works. But i would like to know whether there may be a better way to do it such as plt.plot but allowing me to set the x-axis as Quarters and the other 2 columns as lines?

`df1= df.set_index('Quarters').plot(figsize=(10,5), grid=True)`

Dataframe (from my csv file):

```
| Quarters | Tourism Receipts | Visitors |
| 2019 Q1  | 10               | 1        |
| 2019 Q2  | 20               | 2        |
| 2019 Q3  | 30               | 3        | 
| 2019 Q4  | 40               | 4        |
```

I understand this following method

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title
plt.xlabel
plt.ylabel
```

I would like to enquire whether there is a way to do transform the 'df.set_index' method to plt instead?

Comment: The graph looks like this with my current code: https://imgur.com/a/N9CXSV0 (sorry, i am unable to upload it together with my question)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually combine both, using the `.plot` method which saves a lot of effort from `pd` and use `matplotlib` features side-by-side to customize the output.

This is a sample code of who to address this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 10))

df.set_index('Quarters')[['Tourism Receipts', 'Visitors']].plot(figsize=(10,5), grid=True, ax=ax)

ax.set_yticks(range(-10, 41, 5))
# ax.set_yticklabels( ('{}%'.format(x) for x in range(0, 101, 10)), fontsize=15)
ax.set_xticks(df.Quarters)
ax.set_xticklabels(["{} Q{}".format('2019', x) for x in df.Quarters])
ax.legend(loc='lower left')
```

You can do the same for `yticks` as well.

PS: The `df.Quarters` doesn't include year, so I am assuming 2019.
[image]

Comment: hi @iDrwish - thank you for your help. I copy pasted the code and was faced with a long message of error that I am unsure of how i should resolve it... Here is the image: https://imgur.com/a/yR7QMRU

Comment: This refers to the format error in `df.Quarter` such that it can't be used as an axis. Can you expand your data sample to include some of those rows?

Comment: @Grappyzxc what is the data type for column `Quarter`.

Comment: it states object

Comment: What does the following return: `type(df.Quarters.iloc[0])`? @Grappyzxc

Comment: It returns 'str' @iDrwich

Comment: Since the column is being casted as `object` this means there are some values that are not string. Can you try: `ax.set_xticks(df.Quarters.astype(str))` @Grappyzxc

Comment: It doesn't work, the same long chunk of error message appears. But it seems to work without the set_xticks lines. Furthermore, the labels are appearing already.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it met your inquiry.